# how to add new data and save to database in ag-grid

Tags: polymer, ag-grid

how to add new data and save to database in ag-grid? in https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/ i just get information to insert and remove data but not saving to database.
i use polymer to develope it.

this is the function to add data :

```
fAddBtn: function(){
    var name            = this.$.name.value;
    var email       = this.$.email.value;
    var phone       = this.$.phone.value;
    var website     = this.$.website.value;
    var city            = this.$.city.value;
    var zipcode     = this.$.zipcode.value;

    var newList = {
        'id'            : '43',
        'name'      : name,
        'email'     : email,
        'phone'     : phone,
        'website'   : website,
        'address'   : {
            'city'      : city,
            'zipcode'   : zipcode 
        }
    };
    // this.set('rowData.0', newList);

    this.gridOptions.api.addItems([newList]);
    this.$.addDialog.close();
    this.$.name.value = '';
    this.$.email.value = '';
    this.$.phone.value = '';
    this.$.website.value = '';
    this.$.city.value = '';
    this.$.zipcode.value = '';
},
```

Comment: I don't think ag-grid has a function to directly store in DB, I think you should provide your own one (also because ag-grid cannot know how your DB is structured)

Comment: whats you question? are you asking how to store the json data in a database? what have you tried so far?